# Query two SQL results at the same time

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a query on a table where I have sales for 2 different countries and would like to present the information as the sum of total sales group by country.

The table is as follows:

[image]

And the results that I would like should be as follows:

[image]

The query that I've tried returns the results for one country, but I cannot get both countries in the result. How could I get both results at the same time so it looks as the picture pasted before?

This is the query that I'm currently using:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(amount) 'TOTAL IRELAND SALES', 
    MONTH(DocDate) 'MONTH NUMBER'  
FROM 
    OINV 
WHERE 
    DocDate >= '2020-01-01' 
    AND DocDate <= '2020-12-31' 
    AND Country != 'Spain' 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(DocDate)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is conditional aggregation.  In most databases, this looks like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'Ireland' THEN amount END) as ireland_sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'Spain' THEN amount END) as spain_sales,
       MONTH(DocDate) as month
FROM OINV
WHERE DocDate >= '2020-01-01' AND DocDate < '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(DocDate);
```

Notes:

- Use single quotes only for string and date constants.  Do not use them for column names.
- If you name the columns with no special characters, you do not need to escape the names at all.  Hence, the underscores in the new names.
- Note the change on the date ranges.  This works even when `DocDate` has a time component.
- I would recommend including the year in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`; if in you decide to change the date range, the query will still work.